# Handling field of Integer with specific count of digits in entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am generating entity for a table having a integer field.
In the database the field is set to allow 4 digits.

```
CREATE TABLE REG_DETAIL (
    REG_ID INTEGER (4) DEFAULT J NOT NULL,
    ACTV_CD CHAR    (1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    STATUSCD CHAR    (5) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    DATE_CMPLETED DATE    (4) DEFAULT Y,
)
```

I am generating the entities using Data Explorer in Eclipse.

Generating through Data Explorer does not add any constraint on the integer.

What I would like to know if in JPA 2.0/Hibernate

1. we can have a range added on the integer value accepted in an integer field.
2. or if the number of digits allowed for the integer field can be controlled.

Alternatively if it is different in JPA 2.1

**---UPDATE---**

I was pointed to the Hibernate documentation.
Hibernate provides annotations, Range, Length, Max, Min etc which helps to control the field values

Comment: Hard to understand want You want without code. Do You think about validation annotations, sister / complementary to JPA? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator

Comment: u did it just fine without clearly getting the question. I was looking for the range annotation. i will try to make the question more clear

Comment: General request for many JPA-askers: pls give problematic Java code, not only SQL fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When yo use `@Column` annotation, you can pass a length attribute to it to indicate the length of the field in the database.

`@Column(name = "column_name", length = 10)`

For example, this would create an `INTEGER(10)`.

Also, you can use Bean Validation to specify max and min values with `@Max` and `@Min` annotations.

You can see all the possible options [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e10065).

Comment: thanks for the info. I too realized after I was pointed to the documentation

Comment: better is developing in pure JPA, but using provider extensions (Hibernate, Eslipselink etc) is of-course possible, can give benefits but take portability